# "I am starting learning xyz"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, infinitives, progressive-aspect

Is this sentence correct?

> I am starting learning xyz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is, but *I am starting to learn xyz* might be preferable, if only to avoid the sound of the two *-ing* forms one after the other.

Comment: It should especially be avoided in phrases like "starting learning dancing."

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is not wrong in popular English -- but in "formal" contexts you should prefer something like:

> I am starting to learn xyz.

But, sometimes the former is more suitable. For example

> I'm practicing dancing.

is more common (even formally), than

> I am practicing to dance.

Hence, the bottom line is: use what people are accustomed to hear and read. (unless of course  it's a new coinage)

Comment: I thought ***dancing*** is a noun.